# sshClient CLOSED if non-default password prompt on the server

Tags: java, apache, ssh

My client code uses apache.sshd.SshClient to ssh to a server. If the server has the default password prompt of "Password :", the connection is successful. If the server has any other password prompt, say - "Custom Password Prompt: ", the waitFor immediately returns with ClientSession.CLOSED. The actual username and password are the same in both cases, only the server side password prompt is different. Manual ssh to the server works correctly for all prompts.

I cannot change the password prompt on the server due to security requirements. I only have control on the client code which runs on OSGI. Is there any option in apache sshd or is there any other tried/recommended ssh library which can handle any password prompt from the server?

Thanks.

This is how the code looks -

```
import org.apache.sshd.ClientSession;
import org.apache.sshd.SshClient;
import org.apache.sshd.client.future.ConnectFuture;


class MySshClient {

    ClientSession clientSession;
    SshClient sshClient = SshClient.setUpDefaultClient();
    sshClient.start();

     try {
         ConnectFuture connectFuture = sshClient.connect(username, ipAddress, 22);

         boolean isConnected = false;
         try {
             isConnected = connectFuture.await(timeout);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             throw new CustomException("InterruptedException for connect await");
         }
         if (!isConnected) {
             throw new CustomException("isConnected false");
         }

         clientSession = connectFuture.getSession();
         clientSession.addPasswordIdentity(password);
         try {
             clientSession.auth().await(timeout);
         } catch (InterruptedException e) {
             throw new CustomException("InterruptedException for auth await");
         }

         int ret = clientSession.waitFor(ClientSession.CLOSED | ClientSession.AUTHED, timeout);

         if ((ret & ClientSession.CLOSED) != 0) {
             LOG.error("auth waitFor returned {}",ret);
             throw new CustomException("Session CLOSED !!");
         }
    }
}
```

Output of ssh -vvv

```
$  ssh -vvv test@10.10.10.15
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 10.10.10.15 [10.10.10.15] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Incorrect RSA1 identifier
debug3: Could not load "/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa" as a RSA1 public key
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.8
debug1: Remote protocol version 1.99, remote software version Vendor-1.25
debug1: no match: Vendor-1.25
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.10.10.15" from file "/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:90
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0 
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: setup hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<7680<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug2: bits set: 2080/4096
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA 31:87:7c:12:37:a3:94:06:66:63:35:8c:58:8c:29:c4
debug3: load_hostkeys: loading entries for host "10.10.10.15" from file "/home/username/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: load_hostkeys: found key type RSA in file /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:90
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys
debug1: Host '10.10.10.15' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/username/.ssh/known_hosts:90
debug2: bits set: 2045/4096
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f2fc9581560),
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil)),
debug2: key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil)),
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/username/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/username/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/username/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug2: input_userauth_info_req
debug2: input_userauth_info_req: num_prompts 1
ACS 5.5 Password:
debug3: packet_send2: adding 32 (len 17 padlen 15 extra_pad 64)
debug1: Authentication succeeded (keyboard-interactive).
Authenticated to 10.10.10.15 ([10.10.10.15]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env VNCDESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AGENT_PID
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env COMP_WORDBREAKS
debug3: Ignored env M2
debug3: Ignored env GLADE_PIXMAP_PATH
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env VTE_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env XDG_MENU_PREFIX
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env WINDOWID
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env http_proxy
debug3: Ignored env XTERM_SHELL
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env GLADE_MODULE_PATH
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env ftp_proxy
debug3: Ignored env SESSION_MANAGER
debug3: Ignored env MAVEN_OPTS
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CONFIG_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env DESKTOP_SESSION
debug3: Ignored env QT_QPA_PLATFORMTHEME
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env JAVA_HOME
debug3: Ignored env socks_proxy
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: Ignored env NODE_PATH
debug3: Ignored env https_proxy
debug3: Ignored env XTERM_VERSION
debug3: Ignored env XTERM_LOCALE
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env M2_HOME
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env no_proxy
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env XDG_DATA_DIRS
debug3: Ignored env DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env GLADE_CATALOG_PATH
debug3: Ignored env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env COLORTERM
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 8192 rmax 4096
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: PTY allocation request accepted on channel 0
debug2: channel_input_status_confirm: type 99 id 0
debug2: shell request accepted on channel 0
```

Comment: Could you run "ssh -vvv" to the server, log in, and then [edit] your question to include the output? That will show how the client and server perform authentication.

Comment: Using Jsch instead of sshd fixed the problem